# Does Scalatest have a deep or recursive "should contain theSameElementsAs"?

Tags: scala, scalatest

While Scalatest's `actual should contain theSameElementsAs expected` compares the Sequences `actual` and `expected` in an order-agnostic manner, Sequences that are members of each compared element are compared in an order-aware manner. Is there a variant of `theSameElementsAs` that recursively calls itself on Sequences within elements?

For example, let's say we have the following classes:

```
case class A(
  id: String,
  bs: Seq[B]
)

case class B(
  id: String
)
```

We've also created a test that validates business logic for these classes:

```
val expectedOutput = Array(
  A(
    id = "abc",
    bs = Array(
     B(id = "def"))),
  A(
    id = "rst",
    bs = Array(
      B(id = "uvw"),
      B(id = "xyz"))))

val actualOutput = myBusinessLogic(...)

actualOuptut should contain theSameElementsAs expectedOutput
```

Because `myBusinessLogic` happens to be a Spark app that returns the instances of `A` and the contained instances of `B` in an indeterminate order, `actualOutput` looks like this:

```
Array(
  A(
    id = "rst",
    bs = List(
      B(id = "xyz"),
      B(id = "uvw"))),
   A(
    id = "abc",
    bs = List(
     B(id = "def"))))
```

The assertion fails since `xyz` and `uvw` are in a different order within their `A.bs` field, but this is still valid behavior according to our spec. How would I make the assertion pass here?

Comment: I don't know of any such function, but you could always order both the expected output and actual output by something like id so they're actually in the same order.